# LoadLibrary failure: The specified module could not be found

Tags: r

How could I fix it ?

During startup -

```
Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
In addition: Warning message:
R graphics engine version 15 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed.
```

this is my error

Comment: Please, add some details. Are you opening Rstudio? If so, add the `Rstudio` tag. Please report OS, R and Rstudio versions you are using.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. You need to update your version of RStudio https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/

Comment: I've installed last version of Rstudio! should I delete and download it again? @MrFlick

Comment: I use 3.6.1 version of R

Comment: What is the exact version of RStudio you are running. You said your R version was 3.6.1 but that error message above is using a path for R  4.2.1.M so that doesn’t match up so that’s odd.

Comment: I change my R version. it's 4.2.1 and my Rsudio is 2022.07.1  now... but I can't install faraway even!

Comment: During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Comment: > install.packages("faraway")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/faraway_1.0.8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 770341 bytes (752 KB)
downloaded 752 KB

Comment: Do you have a hidden file in your home directory named `.Renviron`? You can check with `file.exists("~/.Renviron")`

Answer (score 1):

It is a PATH and permission problem. I have solved this problem of missing dll as below:

1. Changed R and RStudio installations to my admin user
2. Following @kevinushey in [this link](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-load-shared-object-on-startup-in-rstudio-only/33107/3) which called my attention to my empty Sys.which("stats.dll"), I added ALL the following paths to my PATH in Windows (but the last two seemed to make the difference):

   - C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\x64;
   - C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin\i386;
   - C:\PROGRA1\R\R-421.1\bin\x64;
   - C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\R\R-4.2.1\library\rJava\jri;
   - C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\library\stats;
   - C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\R\bin\x64;
   - C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\R\library\stats\libs\x64;
3. Moved out 'Rprofile.site' from the below folder following @lrasmus in this issue
   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\R\R-4.2.1\etc

I faced this problem while trying to run nrlx package in R (connection with R and NetLogo) while running the R-extension. I have posted this [answer](https://github.com/rdotnet/rdotnet/issues/71#issuecomment-1363953187) in R.NET issues page. I hope this helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33482311)

Comment: Thanks for the direction, @chrslg. I'm still learning how to use stackoverflow.